# Why does calling transform() on test data return an error that the data is not fitted yet?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

While performing feature scaling, instead of assigning a variable to `StandardScaler()`, when coded like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

x_train = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x_train)

x_test = StandardScaler().transform(x_test)
```

It gives the following error:

> NotFittedError: This StandardScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call
> 'fit'
> with appropriate arguments before using this method.

whereas, following code works fine (after giving an identifier to `StandardScaler()`):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc_x = StandardScaler()

x_train = sc_x.fit_transform(x_train)

x_test = sc_x.transform(x_test)
```

Here, `x_train` is the training dataset and x_test is the test dataset.

Can someone please explain that and why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `StandardScaler()`, you create a *new* (a.k.a. unfitted) object of the standscaler class. If you want to use it, you have to fit it before you can transform any data with it.

What you "told" the code to do was (pseudocode):

1. Create a new scaler object
2. Fit it to your training data
3. Create *another new* scaler object
4. Don't fit it to anything, but use it to transform some data

In the secod example, you created a single scaler object, fitted it to your data, then used *the same* object to transform your test data (which is the correct method to use)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Its always recommended to use `fit()` on the train data-set and `transform()` on the test data-set. As the `μ` and `σ` is calculated from the training data set, the same needs to be applied to normalize the test data set.

avoid using `fittransform()` as it combines both the steps on train data-set.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has posted code to fix the issue, per @G. Anderson's answer, the solution code would be:

```
# create a Scaler object and fit it to your training data
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)

# scale x_train and x_test
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
```